# wp_list_pages, links only for pages with no children

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages

Is this possible to do, and what is a best practice solution?

The things I can think of is parsing the page structure myself, or do it with JQuery to convert `<a>` to `<span>` or similar. Is there a CSS solution?

This is for a left-hand indented menu a la the ones in legacy windows help files or PDF table of content panes.

A sidebar tree menu, if you will, where only the 'leaves' of the tree are clickable (the 'end nodes').

I have the `wp_list_pages` menu working, but I want to make the links that have children unclickable.

Menu is [here](http://ubifon.se/prototyp/)

The only links that should be clickable are:

Hjalp

Intro

Policy

Om

Att Ringa

Att Ringa

Aut-telefonist

Hanvisning Trio

Trio Web

Comment: Are you looking for a navigation menu in your sidebar? Your question is very unclear

Comment: Yes. "This is for a left-hand indented menu". wp_list_pages outputs a navigation menu.

Comment: What have you done so far. Have you registered and added the sidebar? Please edit your question to include what you've tried up to now, working or not working

Comment: There, some more info.

Comment: You may just want to add another menu. http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: I would agree with that. Unfortunately I can't post code from my phone. Will post later

Answer (score 0):

To create the menu in the first place, feel free to use the shortcode `[AVIA_tree_menu root="your_root_document_title"]` by adding this to `functions.php`:

```
function sc_AVIA_tree_menu($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('root' => 'Start',), $atts));  //default if empty.
    $page = get_page_by_title($root);

    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $page->ID,
        'date_format' => get_option('date_format'),
        'depth' => 0,
        'echo' => 0,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'title_li' => __($root)
    );
    echo '<ul>' . wp_list_pages($args) . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode('AVIA_tree_menu', 'sc_AVIA_tree_menu');
```

Style the links that have no children to not look clickable thusly:

```
.pagenav ul li > a {
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.pagenav ul li.page_item_has_children > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Thereafter, prevent clicks by adding this, for example to `document.ready` in `your_theme/js/functions.js`:

```
$('.pagenav li.page_item_has_children > a').click(function () {return false;});
```

I will accept another answer that is as good or better in some way. Happy weekend!